How to generate function with trivial dependency
Given
syms x y z ;
w = 3 * z
wn = matlabFunction(w)

Matlab actually produces a function of only z, so that wn(1,1,1) gets "too many arguments".
How can I get it to produce a function that depends on all of x, y and z?

Note - I need to do this so that I can feed this function into another process that takes functions of x, y, z that might or might not strictly depend on each. I also want the code to mimic the algebra. I am not looking for someone to say - well, show me the whole code and I will rearrange it. I am quite able to rewrite the code by manually making sure that the right arguments are provided. Or having a configuration structure. Or using strings to force the issue. And so on. What I am looking for is a method to get Matlab to simply give me a function with the right argument list instead of being too smart for its own good.

If you define your anonymous function as a function of 3 variables x, y, z you need them to appear in the definition. Does w = @(x,y,z) z + x*0 + y*0 not work?

or something like w=@(x,y,z) [x,y,z] or any other arrangement (with cell array: w=@(x,y,z) {x;y;z}). If you tell your anonymous function to take 3 arguments in, you must also tell the function what to do with each of them. In your example, what did you expect MATLAB to do with x and y in your function w ?

Your question seems to have a typo. wn = matlabFunction(wn(x,y,z)) errors because wn is undefined. You probably meant wn = matlabFunction(w(x,y,z)). I have edited your question. Please revert if my edit is not correct

@CrisLuengo Luis answered the question straight up, which I greatly appreciate. Part of my requirement here is metalogical. But, it would take too long to explain the details, and if I did that, people would just try to equivocate and rewrite all my code with a different philosophy. You don't have to understand the rest of the context for you to be able to answer the question as stated - instead of complaining that you don't see the rest of the context. And yes - I greatly appreciate information I have got from stack overflow in the past. But, I know that people go weird like this some times.

"You don't have to understand the rest of the context for you to be able to answer the question as stated". It is all very well to ask a question with/about a different philosophy than the mainstream, but as written this question and answer is only helpful to one single person: you. If you do not explain what philosophy you're implementing and some reasonning behind it, this whole post has absolutely no interesting information for the rest of the community. It is almost the opposite of the purpose of this site, where quality answers to quality questions will go on to help future users ...

@CrisLuengo - in my experience the two functions are not identical. For example, one version gets numerical floating point errors (in some cases) where the other does not. As far as I can tell from the documentation and my usage - matlabFunction converts a symbolic function into a numeric function. Which is, under the circumstances, what I am looking for. Since I found the question important, it may well be that other people in a similar situation would also. But, you went out of your way to attack the question rather than discussing the context with me.

@CrisLuengo and you deleted my example to explain what effect I was looking for. Are you scared that I might have a point?

@CrisLuengo Well, I hope future readers read both sides and realize that in this context I was asking about vars. And you insisted on talking about something else and would not listen. This following is an extract of lines from the actual code. Is that okay, or should I hand you the keyboard and the entire code file and my job description so you can understand the context.
syms u b x v pb px pv ;
ATV = lg(10-10*((u/uo)*(v/vo)))
algebraic.ATV = ATV;
vars = {u,b,x,v,pb,px,pv};
numeric.ATV = matlabFunction(algebraic.ATV,'vars',vars);

@CrisLuengo the bit I needed was the 'vars' option. And I am genuinely grateful to the chap who presented me with this.

So your actual code does use a symbolic function. Why did you change that to use a numeric, anonymous function in your question? And when I told you that w was already a numeric function, why did you go on a rant instead of fixing the question to match your actual problem? All of this could have been so much easier...

@CrisLuengo My rant, as you pose it, was in response to your rant. I used an anonymous function to emphasize that the real thing I needed was control over the argument list in constructing functions using matlabFunction. A point that you appear never to have fully understood. Rather than engaging me you chose to demand that the person who answered usefully should not have answered at all - because you did not like the way I posed the question.

@CrisLuengo and stop editing the question you are literally and seriously getting the wrong idea. It is specifically trivial dependencies that are the issue here. When f(x,y)=x. So that matlab tends to "helpfully" drop the y. I am going to guess that your mathematical background is slim. My context is mathematical. You have degenerated to complaining about differences in terminology background. And changing the meaning to something other than I want it to mean.

In matlabFunction you can use the optional 'Vars' input  to specify which input variables the produced anonymous function should have:
wn = matlabFunction(w, 'Vars', {x y z});


@CrisLuengo You're totally right. I failed to see the big picture

@LuisMendo Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. The fact that several of the commenters missed the core point that I was looking for how to specify the argument list in the use of matlabFunction explains why I put the cautionary note on my post. Although - clearly, it did not work. Such is the internet today. And you did see the big picture. You saw that I was asking generically, not asking about the specific code snippet.

@CrisLuengo entirely seriously - I am a professional programmer with only mild experience with Matlab. I hunted around and did not find a good answer to this - so I asked here. Luis gave me the answer. Given that you knew that this was indeed what I was looking for, in what sense does the question not make sense? I did say, ignore the unstated context, I just want to know how to do the above. I guess to avoid silly answers maybe I should have used an expression instead? Why do people respond in this weird way. Serious question. Do you have a polite serious answer? I sure don't.
